# Kafka: Docker container and NoBrokersAvailable error

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I run Kafka using:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.99.100 --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

According to https://ngeor.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/kafka-with-docker-a-docker-introduction/
- the -p flag is used to publish a network port. Inside the container, ZooKeeper listens at 2181 and Kafka at 9092. If we don’t publish them with -p, they are not available outside the container, so we can’t really use them.
- the –env flag sets up environment variables. These are needed as per the documentation of the spotify/kafka image
- the last part specifies the image we want to run: spotify/kafka

Now I want to sent messages with a producer to this kafka port. From within another docker container:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                         value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
```

However this gives the error: kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

How could I make sure that the two Docker containers could communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of localhost, you have to provide the docker container IP in which Kafka server is running.

Like

> producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=':9092',
>                            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

Comment: Use the container ID to run:
docker inspect <container ID>
At the bottom,under "NetworkSettings", you can find "IPAddress"

Comment: But the next error appears: KafkaTimeoutError. I created a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261501/kafka-errors-kafkatimeouterror-kafkatimeouterror-failed-to-update-metadata-aft